# I'm trying to make a message appear on screen with the php $_GET statements but they're just coming up blank

Tags: php, html

```
<html>
<?php

    $firstName = isset ($_GET["firstName"]);
    $lastName = isset ($_GET["lastName"]);

    if(isset($_GET['firstName'])&& isset($_GET['lastName'])){
        if (isset($_GET['firstName']) == "Kory" && isset($_GET['lastName']) == " ") {
            echo "Hello Kory";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_GET['firstName'])&& isset($_GET['lastName'])){
        if (isset($_GET['firstName']) == " " && isset ($_GET['lastName']) == "Glover") {
            echo "Hello";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_GET['firstName'])&& isset($_GET['lastName'])){
        if (isset($_GET['firstName']) == " " && isset($_GET['lastName']) == " ") {
            echo "Hello";
        }
    }

?>
</html>
```

Comment: `isset` will just tell you if a value is set for the variable. You shouldn't use it for value comparisons.

Comment: You're comparing `isset($_GET['firstName'])` with other strings; but it's only going to return a boolean, so the comparisons are never going to be successful

Answer (score 2):

why not just this:

```
if(isset($_GET['firstName'])&& isset($_GET['lastName'])){
    echo $_GET['firstName']." ".$_GET['lastName'];
}
```

the reason why this does not work is this:

```
if (isset($_GET['firstName']) == "Kory" && isset($_GET['lastName']) == " ")
if (true or false) == "Kory" will never be true
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `isset()` checks if a variable is set (see the [doc](http://php.net/isset)). Once you know that it is set, you just need to use `$_GET`. You only need to check whether the variables are set once, so you code can be minimized to this:

```
$firstName = $_GET["firstName"];
$lastName = $_GET["lastName"];

if (isset($_GET['firstName']) && isset($_GET['lastName'])) {
  if ($firstName == "Kory" && $lastName == " ") {
    echo "Hello Kory";
  }

  if ($firstName == " " && $lastName == "Glover") {
    echo "Hello";
  }

  if ($firstName == " " && $lastName == " ") {
    echo "Hello";
  }
}
```